# Student model overfitting in multiclass classification with knowledge distillation

Tags: overfitting, knowledge-distillation

I'm working on an OCT multiclass classification task using knowledge distillation. My teacher model achieves a solid 97% accuracy and its loss curve demonstrates good stability and generalization. However, I'm facing an issue with my student model.

My teacher model is a: VGG19 based Transfer learning model with CBAM block

Student model is a: VGG16 based Transfer learning model

Optimizer: `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.001)`

**Problem**:

While the student model achieves a decent accuracy of 97.71%, its training and validation loss curves exhibit significant oscillations, indicating potential overfitting.

**Distillation setup for the mentioned graph**:

1. Alpha: 0.8
2. Beta: 1.0
3. Temperature: 2
4. Distillation Loss Function: Huber loss function

**Attempted solutions**:

1. I've explored data augmentation techniques, but haven't observed significant improvement.
2. I have tried different alpha values: 0.2-0.8, same issues
3. I have tried Different Temperature values: 2-8, same issues.
4. I have trained the model without Early Stopping, it produced more oscillations in the curve
5. I have tried other distillation loss function such as: KLDivergence loss, MSE loss, CategoricalFocalCrossentropy etc , almost same issue

**Accuracy and Loss curve of the student model**: https://ibb.co/3cvmys8

This is distillator class:

```
class Distiller(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, student, teacher):
        super(Distiller, self).__init__()
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student = student

    def compile(
        self,
        optimizer,
        metrics,
        student_loss_fn,
        distillation_loss_fn,
        alpha=0.75,
        temperature=2,
        beta = 1.0
    ):
        """ Configure the distiller.
        Args:
            optimizer: Keras optimizer for the student weights
            metrics: Keras metrics for evaluation
            student_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between student
                predictions and ground-truth
            distillation_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between soft
                student predictions and soft teacher predictions
            alpha: weight to student_loss_fn and 1-alpha to distillation_loss_fn
            temperature: Temperature for softening probability distributions.
                Larger temperature gives softer distributions.
        """
        super(Distiller, self).compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
        self.student_loss_fn = student_loss_fn
        self.distillation_loss_fn = distillation_loss_fn
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = 1.0  # Initial beta factor
        self.temperature = temperature
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack data
        x, y = data
        # Forward pass of teacher
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x, training=False)
        #model = ...  # create the original model
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x, training=False)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass of student
            # Forward pass of student
            student_predictions = self.student(x, training=True)
            # Compute losses
            student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
            distillation_loss = (
                self.distillation_loss_fn(
                    tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                    tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                )
                * self.temperature**2
            )

           # loss = self.alpha * student_loss +  distillation_loss
            loss = self.alpha * student_loss + self.beta * distillation_loss
        # Update beta (optional decay strategy, adjust as needed)
            # Update beta (optional decay strategy, adjust as needed)
            # Update beta (optional decay strategy, adjust as needed)
            # Update beta (optional decay strategy, adjust as needed)
            self.beta = max(0.0, min(self.beta - 0.01, 1.0))



        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update the metrics configured in `compile()`.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions)
        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update(
            {"student_loss": student_loss, "distillation_loss": distillation_loss}
        )
        return results
    def test_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data
        x, y = data
        # Compute predictions
        y_prediction = self.student(x, training=False)
        # Calculate the loss
        student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, y_prediction)
        # Update the metrics.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_prediction)
        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update({"student_loss": student_loss})
        return results
```